# AJAX success failure callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a table and I have a delete button. Basically what I want to do is when I click on the delete button, it will send a DELETE request to our server and update on the db. If it's successful, it will remove that row from the table.

Config.js

```
var SiteConfigProxy = function () {
"use strict";

var getSiteConfig = Config.apiUrl + "/configs/site/{siteId}";
var addDevice = Config.apiUrl + "/configs/device/{deviceId}";

var delete1 = function (url, data, done, fail){
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof (done) === 'function') done(data);
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            if (typeof (fail) === 'function') fail(data);
        }
    });
};

return {
    deleteDeviceConfig: function (deviceId, data, done, fail){
        delete1(addDevice.replace("{deviceId}", deviceId), data, done, fail);
    }
};
} ();
```

siteconfig.js

```
        configTable.on("click", ".delete", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this row?")) {
            var tableRow = $(this).parents("tr")[0];
            var data = {
                siteId: tableData.fnGetData(tableRow)[1],
                hostname: tableData.fnGetData(tableRow)[2]
            };

            SiteConfigProxy.deleteDeviceConfig(tableData.fnGetData(tableRow)[0], data,
                function(data){
                    tableData.fnDeleteRow(tableRow);
                    console.log("delete succeeded");
                },
                function(data){
                    console.log("delete failed");
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

Right now every time when I click on the button, it won't remove that row and the console won't log that statement. I am just wondering why the success and failure callback isn't working.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are there any errors in the console log? If you check the browser's Network tab, do you see it sending the AJAX request?

Comment: @Barmar there is no error in the console log. The ajax request is actually sent and I can see the row has been removed in the db

Comment: Do you see the JSON response in network tab?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't see the JSON response hmm

Comment: Where in the documentation do you see a `failure` option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your server script is not returning a valid JSON response, it should invoke the failure callback (because attempting to parse the response as JSON fails). But the correct name of that option is `error:`, not `failure:`. So change it to:

```
    error: function (data) {
        if (typeof (fail) === 'function') fail(data);
    }
```

If the server isn't supposed to send back a JSON response, leave out the `dataType:` option, and it won't try to parse it.

Comment: Now I can see console log "deleted failed" but why is it returning error if the request is being processed over the server side and updated on db?

Comment: Because the server is not sending back correct JSON. Since you specified `dataType: 'json'`, an error parsing the response causes the `error:` handler to be invoked.

Comment: ok now I see why. Is there a way to specify a different datatype for response ? because my response is not a json type. Or can I just discard the response data?

Comment: Just leave out the `dataType:` option, and it will default according to the `Content-type:` header in the response.